# How to use DataTables to implement paging for two-row records?

Tags: jquery, datatables

Got a record set with too many fields. The display of a record runs into a second row. See the screenshot below:

[image]

That two-row display of records broke the paging provided by [DataTables](https://datatables.net/)
With an exception:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined

The DataTables failed because there is no regular columns in the table. Is there some feature to process this kind of multi-row record tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try breaking the information and putting some of it into a child row using [row().child()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().child())

Here's a full implementation example from the website:

https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html